# javascript validation for name,contact numbers

Tags: asp.net

I have created 2 pages login and signup..On signup form I have used javascript for nonempty fields. Now I want to add validation for **characters only, digits and date**.

How to write these additional validations in my function. Please help. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validateform() {

        var Firstname = document.getElementById("txtfirst").value;

        if (Firstname == "First Name" || Firstname == ""){
            alert("Firstname must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

and I have called this function on `onClientClick` event of signup button.

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: OP wants to limit input to **characters only, digits and date** (what?).

Comment: `onClienClick` event?

Comment: characters only for firstname,middlename,surname and digits only for contact number,invalid date for date..i have written above code for all empty fields validation.now i want to add these validations

Answer (score 0):

Code to check alpha characters:

```
function onlyAlpha(inputtext){   
    var acceptedChars= /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
    if(inputtext.value.match(acceptedChars)){  
        alert('ok'); 
        return true;  
    } else {  
        alert('input alphabet characters only');  
        return false;  
    }
}
```

you can call this function on onblur on onClick with inputtext parameter as u wish to validate and the same way u can   apply digits validation too.

Comment: But how can I call 2 or more functions on same button?because i have already called validateform() function on signup button

Answer (score 0):

There are n number of methods to validate name. Let me share my view

Method 1

First Name:

```
lname=document.getElementById('lname').value;
    namelen=/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15})+$/;
    if(!namelen.test(lname))
    {
        alert('Enter a name');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('splname').innerHTML="";
    }

returnValue;
}
```

Method 2 - To color the background

```
namelen=document.getElementById('lname').value.length;
    lname=document.getElementById('lname').value;
    if((namelen=<5 || namelen >=12) || !isNaN(lname))
    {
        document.getElementById('splname').innerHTML="Enter a name";
        document.getElementById('lname').style.background="red";
        document.getElementById('lname').focus();               
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('splname').innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById('lname').style.background="green";
    }
returnValue;
}
```

Method 3

```
fname=document.getElementById('fname').value;
    namelen=/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15})+$/;
    if(!namelen.test(fname))
    {
        document.getElementById('spfname').innerHTML="Enter a name";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('spfname').innerHTML="";
    }
```